# i cant seeem to get this text under this icon

Tags: html, css

i try to get the green text under the wallet text and icon but i just cant get it to work, also why is the responsiveness so weird here?

https://jsfiddle.net/8dxt0hkj/2/ <-- take a look at the code here

thanks in advance

```
<div class="wallet">
    <span class="wallettext">
        Wallet 
        <img src="imgs/wallet.png" class="wallet_icon">
    </span>
    <p class="wallet_value">$35,95</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Yannick. What do you mean when you say the responsiveness is weird? Can you tell us exactly what you see happening that you don't want to have happen, and explain or give an example of what you do want to see? More details will make it easier for us to help you solve the problem.

Comment: Improve code readability

Answer (score 0):

To put the green text under the wallet text and icon, you will need to change the CSS for wallet_value. You could change `display: inline-block;` to `display: block;` to make wallet_value start on the next line (and therefore appear below the wallet text and icon.) This will make the text hug the left edge of the page, though, so if you want the text to line up better you can also add `margin-left: 30px;`.

I also noticed that in this line:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search for..."">
```

You have an extra " character that might be messing things up. Try changing that line to:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search for...">
```

*Edit:* It sounds like you want everything inside the header div to be all on one line and change size as needed when the window resizes so that the header always fits on one line. Here is an [edited JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8dxt0hkj/26/) with working code (as close as I can to what I think you're asking how to do.) I used the `display: flex` option a lot in this, so I recommend checking out [this tutorial](https://flexboxfroggy.com/) and/or [this documentation](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if you're not familiar with flex.

I set the header to `display: flex;`. I also put `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` on the wallet div so that it will display one element on top of the other as you asked for. I made the search bar change width dynamically by removing the absolute width and making it have a `min-width: 80px;` instead, along with `width: 100%;`. Then, when I set its parent to have `flex-grow: 1;` the search bar will stretch to fill the remaining space. I also took out some of the large margins that were making things too wide, and I set the min-width of the header as a whole to 700px so it won't get too small when the window resizes. Is that about what you were looking for?

Comment: header will get smaller than 100% width. thanks so much

Comment: I think I see what you might mean - when I resize the result window in your JSFiddle, the search bar jumps down below the top bar when the window is less than 1164px wide, and the wallet text and image also jump up on the same line as the search bar. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Did you want the wallet text and icon to stay inside the top header bar all the time? If so, I think I know how you can do that, but I'll need to change my previous answer.

Comment: @YanickPalmers did this answer your question? If it was helpful, please consider accepting it so others can find it more easily. If not, please let me know what you still would like help with.